# How to take out single element out of list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have list as follows:

```
list = [u'windows 32bit', u'i7', u'5Mb', u'energenie_eu', u'nvidia_970']
```

I want to take out value '5Mb' out of it. So, suggest me how can i take out value '5Mb' seperated from the list and have list as :

```
[u'windows 32bit', u'i7', u'energenie_eu', u'nvidia_970']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove elements by item

```
list.remove("5Mb")
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also do,

```
A = L[:n]+L[n+1:]
```

if you wanted a copy of the list wihout the element to work with. You could use 
L.index  to find n if you only know the list item by value rather than position - though then you are back to L.remove and the time penalty for searching the list.